# Installing locales in docker env not working

Tags: python, django, docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to use

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ar_AE.UTF-8')
```

In Django app, that running in docker environment, with python:3.9.6-slim

But it gives me unsupported locale setting error

I tried to install locales in Dockerfile using

```
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/'        /etc/locale.gen \
&& sed -i -e 's/# ar_AE.UTF-8 UTF-8/ar_AE.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
&& locale-gen

ENV LANG ar_AE.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL ar_AE.UTF-8
```

But it didn't fix the problem

Anyone know how to solve this please

Answer (score 0):

You should also install locales-all package:

apt-get install -y locales locales-all